# calculate clustering coefficient

Tags: python, network-programming, networkx

I want to calculate the clustering coefficient of a network without the built in method from NetworkX.

The method I've written right now seems to exactly what is

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

#create graph
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(0,1),(0,2),(0,4),(0,3),(0,5),(1,7),(1,10),(1,11),(1,12),(2,4),(2,5),(2,3),(3,4),(5,8),(5,6),(6,8),(6,9),(6,7),(7,9),(7,10),(10,11),(10,12),(11,13),(12,13)])

# print 1 test value
print nx.clustering(G,1)

def clustering_coefficient(G):
    # this will store the mapping of node/coefficient
    clusteringDict = {}
    for node in G:

        neighboursOfNode = []
        nodesWithMutualFriends = []

        # store all neighbors of the node in an array so we can compare
        for neighbour in G.neighbors(node):
            neighboursOfNode.append(neighbour)

        for neighbour in G.neighbors(node):
            for second_layer_neighbour in G.neighbors(neighbour):
                # compare if any second degree neighbour is also a first degree neighbour (this makes a triangle)
                # if so, append it to the mutual friends list
                if second_layer_neighbour in neighboursOfNode:
                    nodesWithMutualFriends.append(second_layer_neighbour)

        # filter duplicates from the mutual friend array
        nodesWithMutualFriends = list(set(nodesWithMutualFriends))

        clusteringCoefficientOfNode = 0
        # apply coefficient formula to calculate
        if len(nodesWithMutualFriends):
            clusteringCoefficientOfNode =  (2 * float(len(nodesWithMutualFriends)))/((float(len(G.neighbors(node))) * (float(len(G.neighbors(node))) - 1)))

        clusteringDict[node] = clusteringCoefficientOfNode

clustering_coefficient(G)
```

However, when running this script, the NetworkX value will most of the time give a different value then my own script. Somehow this script is also able to run up to 2.0 instead of 1.0.

What is wrong with my logic?

Comment: Are you after a single clustering coefficient of the network?  Or the clustering of each node?

Comment: I'm looking for the coefficient of each node in a network @Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one problem comes from the following:

```
 clusteringCoefficientOfNode =  (2 * float(len(nodesWithMutualFriends)))/((float(len(G.neighbors(node))) * (float(len(G.neighbors(node))) - 1)))
```

If node 1 has N neighbors all of whom are also neighbors of one another, then each neighbor appears in `nodeWithMutualFriends` exactly once - because you've used `set`, despite being in N-1 triangles.  You then multiply by 2, so you've got 2N/(N*(N-1)) = 2/(N-1).  But you should have 1.  So really you aren't counting the number of triangles.  You're counting the number of nodes in triangles.  Then you're dividing by the number of possible triangles.

So you can fix it by removing the `set` call and by removing the `2*`.

Comment: I see.. Should I then remove of the 2 * because of this implementation? There is still something else wrong as well, because also then some values are off (try running the script and play a little with the nx values on one of the first lines)

Comment: see the edit I made.  Your problem comes because you used `set`.  So you lose track of how many triangles the node is in.